# Do any USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet adapter work with OS X?

Tags: macos, usb, ethernet

YI know there is a solution available from Apple for Thunderbolt.  I also know there is a solution available from Apple for USB 2.0 to fast Ethernet (10/100).

What I am looking for an adapter to plug into a USB 3.0 port, providing me Gigabit (10/100/1000) LAN capability via wired Ethernet.

Are there any recommendations for a USB3 to Gigabit Ethernet adapter compatible with macOS?

Comment: USB 3 is just too new, and no one has developed a Gigabit USB 3 NIC yet? Looks like it will be a waiting game.

Comment: In the same boat here. Loving the new 2012 Macbook Air, but I use an external monitor at work, and I'd like to use Gigabit Ethernet as well (on a Avid ISIS). Either a Thunderbolt splitter cable (or hub) or a USB 3 to Gigabit Ethernet and we'd be all set. Buying a 27" Apple Thunderbolt monitor is lovely, but not a cheap solution.

Comment: See also: [this Super User question](http://superuser.com/questions/380790/usb-3-to-gigabit-ethernet-adaptors-where-are-they).

Comment: I can say the new thunderbolt gigabit ethernet adapter is working very well for me despite the allure of having the thunderbolt port free when I care to use a DP display.

Answer (score 7):

**StarTech** makes the [USB31000S](http://intrl.startech.com/Networking-IO/Adapter-Cards/USB-3-to-Gigabit-Ethernet-NIC-Network-Adapter~USB31000S), which is a USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet adapter with support for VLANs, jumbo frames and checksum offloading. List price is about **USD 55**.

These are based on the [ASIX AX88179 chip](http://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=131;71;112), which has drivers for **OS X 10.6 - 10.8** [available](http://www.asix.com.tw/FrootAttach/driver/AX88179_Macintosh_10.6_10.7_Driver_v1.1.0_Binary.zip) (bottom of previous link). Any other product using this chip would also work.

Comment: I have 10.8.2 and the drivers (even 1.3) are a bit finicky for the AX88179... but I can get it to work.

Comment: I used to have a ax88179 based adapter, the driver is buggy. The adapter won't wake up if your computer went to a sleep. A reboot or re-plug is needed.

Comment: For me, it works on 10.7 but not after upgrade to 10.8  on an MacBook Air. On my new MacBook Pro (2016) it does not work at all under either 10.8 or Windows 10. So my advice would be to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

It's not USB 3.0, but the [Belkin F5D5055](http://www.belkin.com/uk/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=256915) USB 2.0 Gigabit Ethernet adapter is supported out the box by 10.7 (haven't checked 10.6) and delivers better performance than the Apple 10/100Mbps adapter. I can get speeds of around 35MB/s with my mid-2011 i7 Air.

Comment: Do you need to replug the usb adapter after waking up the mac from a several minutes sleep?

Comment: No, not usually. Perhaps once a month (or maybe less frequently) I'd have to do that, but it wasn't a common occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  I have personally used [Anker's USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter](http://radnex.us/Anker_USB3-Gig-Ethernet_Adapter) on my MacBook Pro computers (2008 and 2011), iMac, Surface Pro and various laptops.  As far as OS X goes, it worked with 10.8 through 10.10

Update:  It has been tested to work on El Capitan (10.11) and macOS Sierra (10.12) with no issues.  It was tested on a MacBook Pro 2011 and a 2012 iMac.

I stick with brands like Anker because of their 18 month warranty.